# HTML5 WebM/OGV on Firefox results in drastic color change

Tags: css, html, firefox, video

I have a HTML5 video with the necessary mp4, WebM and OGV formats.

The problem is that WebM and OGV display differently in Firefox.
i.e. My red color tone changes to an ugly bright pink and quality is lesser.

**Cross-browser testing results summary:**

[image: Screen-shot of results table]

**Question 1:** How do I resolve the inconsistent coloring/quality?

**Question 2:** Should I bother with WebM and OGV if:

1. MP4 works without problem on Firefox, IE, Chrome (and presumably Safari)
2. ...AND if the video isn't presented on screens less than 768px?